# JBoss and MySQL New missing/unsatisfied dependencies

Tags: java, mysql, jboss

I'm a Java and JBoss newbie struggling to get `JBoss AS 7.0.1` working with `mySQL 5.5` on my Windows 10 machine.
I get the following error when I start JBoss:-

> 16:19:39,480 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) Service status report
>      New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
>         service jboss.jdbc-driver.com_mysql (missing)

This is what I've done

1 created directory `jboss-as-7.0.1.Final\modules\com\mysql\main`

2 Files there: `module.xml` and `mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar` (downloaded from official mysql site)

3 Content of module.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.mysql" slot="main">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

4 Relevant parts from jboss-as-7.0.1.Final\standalone\configuration\standalone.xml:

```
        <datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:/jbossdbDS" pool-name="my_pool" enabled="true" jta="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                <connection-url>
                    jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jbossdb
                </connection-url>
                <driver>
                    com.mysql
                </driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>
                        root
                    </user-name>
                    <password>
                        password
                    </password>
                </security>
                <timeout>
                    <idle-timeout-minutes>
                        0
                    </idle-timeout-minutes>
                    <query-timeout>
                        600
                    </query-timeout>
                </timeout>
                <statement>
                    <prepared-statement-cache-size>
                        100
                    </prepared-statement-cache-size>
                    <share-prepared-statements/>
                </statement>
            </datasource>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="H2DS" enabled="true" jta="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                <connection-url>
                    jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
                </connection-url>
                <driver>
                    h2
                </driver>
                <pool>
                    <prefill>
                        false
                    </prefill>
                    <use-strict-min>
                        false
                    </use-strict-min>
                    <flush-strategy>
                        FailingConnectionOnly
                    </flush-strategy>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>
                        sa
                    </user-name>
                    <password>
                        sa
                    </password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql"/>
                <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>
                        org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource
                    </xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
```

Comment: You need to put the MySQL JDBC driver JAR in the CLASSPATH.

Comment: Thanks.  I just set the CLASSPATH system variable to C:\JBOSS\jboss-as-7.0.1.Final\modules\com\mysql\main which is where the file mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar is located, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: JBOSS ignores environment variables, as do all Java EE app servers.  Better to put that JAR in an appropriate place: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/Install_a_JDBC_Driver_as_a_Core_Module1.html

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned the mysql jar file name in modules as

> mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar

But in your module.xml it is incorrectly configured as

> mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar

Pls Correct your module.xml

Your driver configured in datasource with name

```
        <driver>
            com.mysql
        </driver>
```

Update that to your correct driver name as

```
            <driver>
                mysql
            </driver>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses.

Turns out the mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar file was corrupt, the java.sql.Driver file inside it was empty.  Not sure how that happened!